# nuget package not installing dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've created a nuget package which has 2 dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ConsoleApp2</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>ConsoleApp2</title>
    <authors>XX</authors>
    <owners>XX</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2018</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="AutoMapper" version="6.2.2" />
      <dependency id="NHibernate" version="4.0.4.4000" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I would like install this nuget package to other project but it is't download and install AutoMapper or NHibernate and i don't have any reference.
[from csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXQVZ.jpg)
To create nuget package I'm using nuget.exe version 4.6.2 but other version also don't work.

However if I use method with app.config and package.config it's works well, but I need use first method.

**from package.config:**

[image: from package.config]

Answer (score 3):

> nuget package not installing dependencies

Probably you have select the **Ignore Dependencies** for Dependency behavior in the options **Install and Update options** on the nuget package manager UI. To check it, please extend the **options** button:

[image]

If yes, please set it to the default value **Lowest**.

Comment: @jakub, I have found you have set two nuget packages, both of them have this issue when you install it via nuget package manager UI? Could you share your nuget package to me via one-drive, so that I could check it in my side?

Comment: I don't see Dependency Behavior under options.  Visual Studio 2022